# R data.table sorting with SD

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table of the following format:

```
Model    Miles
Toyota   15000
Toyota   20000
Honda    5000
Honda    1000
VW       500
VW       5000
```

I am trying to sort it by such that I get the below output

```
Model   Miles
Toyota  20000
Honda   5000
VW      5000
```

If I try `dt[, .SD[which.max(Miles)], by = 'Model']` I get the correct result.
However, if I want to store 'Miles' in a variable such as mileage and use
`mileage='Miles'`

`dt[, .SD[which.max(c(mileage))], by = 'Model']`
I get
`In which.max(c(mileage)) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Any thoughts on why this happens? I am just switching from using column name directly to storing it in a variable and using it that way.
Thanks!

Comment: Try writing `which.max('Miles')`

Comment: It happens because you are using a string in the second example as a column name (`"Miles"`), while in the first example you are passing the column name without quotes (`Miles`)- it's not the same. data.table, by default, will evaluate unquoted names as column names, while it will treat the quoted column names as just a string (read about NSE vs SE). There are many easy fixes for this. One could be `dt[, .SD[which.max(get(mileage))], by = Model]`

Answer (score 1):

You problem is related to the question of standard evaluation. That's funny, I just wrote a [blog note on the subjet](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/post/datatable/datatable-nse/).

To use variable name within a data.table transformation, there are several ways. I think the easiest in your case is to use  `get(mileage)` as suggested in the comments.

```r
dt[, .SD[which.max(get(mileage))], by = Model]
```